# How to change the key color when printing a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a built in python function that allows me to change the key colors in a dictionary so that I can more effectively distinguish them from their corresponding values?

I am currently using a jupyter notebook and printing out a dictionary and would like it to show something similar to the output below:

```
in:
data
```

Data above is a python dictionary.

```
out: 
{
 key1:value1
 key2:value2
 ...
 keyn:valuen
}
```

Such that the keys are in blue and the values are in a different color. The reason I want to do this is because I am printing a dictionary that varies a lot in key length, therefore making it much harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that you want the colors to show in the output of a print statement then this will do the trick.

```
red = "\033[1;31m"
blue = "\033[1;34m"
green = "\033[1;32m"
no_color = "\033[0m"

out = {
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2',
    'key3' : 'value3' }

for key in out.keys () :
    print (red, key, blue, out [key])
print (no_color)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer builds upon the answer provided by @bashBedlam .

The function below accepts the dictionary that you would like to print, and the formats for the key value pairs in the desired formats.

```
def dprint(d,key_format = "\033[1;32m",value_format = "\033[1;34m"):
    for key in d.keys() :
        print (key_format, key, value_format, d[key])
```